# Boundary Smoothing Algorithms

Tags: computational-geometry, geometry, mesh

I have a 2-manifold with boundary, built with marching cubes. Are there any well-known algorithms for smoothing its boundary edges?

Most of the papers I found are concerned with smoothing the surface.

Thanks!